Trying to access data from a Realme GT Master Edition with broken screen
I'm here today because of a teeny tiny problem with my phone. As it got hotter and hotter (external factors, high usage, high temperatures on charging), the screen glue decided to abandon me, leaving my screen dangling with no protection. The flex cable connecting the mobo and the screen teared apart, hence leaving me with a phone without any visual input.
I've decided to not repair it as it's not worth the cost, but I need to access the data from inside the phone. I already know that with ADB it should be pretty easy to access those. The only problem? When I usually connect the phone to my PC, it shows the pop-up window to select the connection mode (only charging, Android Auto, data transfer, etc) and I need to select the data transfer mode in order to activate ADB.
Do you have a way for me to access ADB with only a cable and a PC or must I try to solder back the flex cable / change the screen? Thanks for reading and for the help!

Unless realme has modified Android adb mode is, once you have activated it, always active and does not need any USB selection dialog. If it doesn't work without in your case you may have installed the wrong drivers for the USB device that is visible before you change the USB mode in the dialog you mentioned. Most likely in charging only mode there is only one adb device and changing to data transfer changes it to one USB compound device plus as children adb device and mtp device.
